# WP CLI not finding plugin commands

Tags: wp-cli

On a Ubuntu 20.04 Linode I have a Wordpress installation. I deploy the website using https://github.com/Mixd/wp-deploy, a Capistrano deployment tool. When the website is deployed the folder structure is like this:

- `current` folder points to the actual release (virtual host points to this folder)
- inside of `current` there are:
- `wordpress` folder with all the Wordpress core files
- and the `content` folder which is `wp-content` renamed and contains plugins, themes, uploads

On my wp-config.php file are defined:

- `define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://website.com/content');`
- `define('WP_SITEURL','https://website.com/wordpress');`

WP CLI is installed and it works with its own basic commands. The deployment is not a problem and it works using WP CLI commands.

The problem arises when I try to use WP CLI commands defined by plugins I have installed, like WP All Import. The error I get is:

`Error: 'all-import' is not a registered wp command. See 'wp help' for available commands.`

Running `wp help` it doesn't list any plugin command. Instead, on my computer, it lists all the commands.

I guess is due to the different folder structure but I'm not able to find a solution. I need to be able to run for example `wp all-import run ID` to run imports from the command line since they're way faster and I have 90k products to edit.

Comment: What does `wp plugin path` give you?

Comment: From inside ```current```, ```wordpress```, and ```content``` it gives ```/plugins``` path

Comment: The only solution I found to fix this right now is to define ```WP_CONTENT_DIR``` constant in ```wp-config.php``` as a absolute path without using ```dirname(__FILE__)``` or ```$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']```. Is it a bad practice? Can this be a harm to the installation?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [WP-CLI r2.0 release blog post](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/2018/08/08/wp-cli-v2-0-0-release-notes/) , for normal use with all commands remove `wp-cli/wp-cli` and require `wp-cli/wp-cli-bundle`

Comment: I'm not sure that answers the question, which was why wp-cli commands registered by plugins wouldn't be working.

Comment: when you install wp cli globally `composer global require wp-cli/wp-cli`  use wp-cli/wp-cli-bundle instead wp-cli/wp-cli